# Embed Vimeo video on secure site

Tags: https, vimeo, vimeo-api

Do I need to do anything differently when embedding a vimeo video on a site using https? I'm currently using the Universal embed:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Is it not working? Can you describe the problem you are encountering?

Comment: I'm actually not seeing an issue but, I wanted to find out if there was anything that I needed to do to ensure that browsers don't alert users that the site they are visiting is displaying both secure and insecure content. I've tested the devices on several different devices and have not received any warnings but I just encountered one individual that did.

Comment: @Clifford, I ran a test on my site with Fiddler2 and received the following error: The remote server (player.vimeo.com) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Comment: @brandozz:  You are addressing the wrong person, my edit was only to get your post off the "embedded" tag which refers to "embedded systems" - software running on something that is not a general purpose computing platform. I know plenty about embedded systems, and nothing about Vimeo. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Comment: @Clifford my apologies

Comment: @Dashron I've decided to just remove the embedded video and self host it.

Comment: @brandozz I think you're getting that because you're using Fiddler2?

Answer (score 1):

From a staff member of Vimeo: http://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:106549

> The insecure content warning is caused by our analytics system, and
>   is unfortunately unavoidable. HTTPS embeds are currently in beta
>   testing and are not fully supported at this time.

"Not fully supported at this time" was July 2013 at which point she mentioned that there is no ETA for that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing extra is required, it should work just fine. The only thing to note is that as of now, video files will not be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it works just fine but, is it good practice to embed a video that is served from http on a site that uses https? Is our secure site no longer considered secure because of this content.